# output appended HTML form elems and vals within <ul> <li> ... </li></ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently, using jQuery `.clone();` to grab current HTML form element *values* *(that have been inserted or toggled by user)* and then appending to my `.results` div element.

Basically user fills out form -> can click 'add button' -> form values appear within `.results` div *(and previous most recent line that was added or cloned removed, when .remove button clicked)*.

I am trying to output each set *(set meaning each time, `.add` was hit)* *within* `<ul>` and `<li>` tags so it will output neater, and I'll have more control of outputs. *I attempted to add this within the same '.appendTo' but was not correct.*

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkRemove()
    $('.add').click(function() {
        $('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], option:selected').clone().appendTo('.results');
        checkRemove();
    });
    $('.remove').click(function() {
        $('input[type=text]:last, input[type=checkbox]:last, option:selected').remove();
        checkRemove();
    });
});
function checkRemove() {
    if ($('input[type=text]').length == 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remove').show();
    }
};
```

---

Again, the above *is* working. I would just like the outputs to occur *within* `<ul><li></li></ul>` HTML tags; so it is cleaner, and easier to style. Currently it is outputting via `.appendTo` directly within `.results` div without format.

Comment: can you please add your html too!

Comment: My HTML is just a HTML web <form> with those 3 options that I am cloning? Then my .add, .remove, and submit buttons (all working, I just need to add <ul> around my .add button's output within .results).

Comment: Showing HTML would be great, it might be trivial still important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the crux.
add a empty ul tag

```
$('.result').html("<ul class='mylist'></ul>");
```

Append a li tag to that list
and then add your clone!

```
$('.mylist').append($('<li>')).append("");
        $('.allinputs input[type=text],.allinputs input[type=checkbox], option:selected').clone().appendTo($('.mylist li:last-child'));;
```

May be you need to modify according to your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.result').html("<ul class='mylist'></ul>");
     checkRemove();
    $('.add').click(function() {
     $('.mylist').append($('<li>')).append("");
        $('.allinputs input[type=text],.allinputs input[type=checkbox], option:selected').clone().appendTo($('.mylist li:last-child'));;
        
        checkRemove();
    });
    $('.remove').click(function() {
        $('input[type=text]:last, input[type=checkbox]:last, option:selected').remove();
        checkRemove();
    });
});
function checkRemove() {
    if ($('input[type=text]').length == 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remove').show();
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allinputs">
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<button class="add">click</button>
</div>
Result<br/>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You should **use appendTo with some jQuery object like $(".results")**. Please check this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkRemove()
    $('.add').click(function() {
        $('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], option:selected').clone().appendTo($('.results'));
        checkRemove();
    });
    $('.remove').click(function() {
        $('input[type=text]:last, input[type=checkbox]:last, option:selected').remove();
        checkRemove();
    });
});
```

To append inside ul tag, use:

```
var elem = $("<ul></ul>");
```

Now,

```
elem.append($("<li></li>").append(
$('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], option:selected').clone()));
```

Comment: Thanks for looking - but, I don't quite understand, would you mind explaining this further and how it might work with my code?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know you wanted to append inside ul tag. I modified changes. Please check if it helps or may be I didn't get exactly what you want.